# How to pass custom variables to the server through ajax?

Tags: php, ajax, variables

I want to send the custom variable to the url like customID:5.how can I add this code.Plz help

```
            $("#e8").select2({
            placeholder: "Search for another Concept",
            minimumInputLength: 1,
            multiple: true,

            ajax: { // instead of writing the function to execute the request we use Select2's convenient helper
                url: "sendchat3.php",
                dataType: 'json',
                data: function (term, page) {
                    return {
                        q: term, // search term
                        page: page
                    };
                },
                results: function (data, page) {
                    return { results: data};

                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Err… you *are* sending custom data already.

Comment: I guess @barryhunter answer should solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

```
...
            data: function (term, page) {
                return {
                    q: term, // search term
                    customID: 5,
                    page: page
                };
            },
...
```

Comment: Why is the OP sending params to a function and then returning an array rather then simply sending an array? Is it a good approach?

Comment: I'm guessing select2 needs a function, because it can may need to make multiple ajax calls, ie if the user pages though the dataset, so it just executes the callback function (which happens to be an anonymys function) to get the 'data' array, rather than having a static array.

Comment: @barryhunter Thanks,and how can i pick it in the server side?

Comment: Well your `sendchat3.php` script must already be reading the `q` and `page` variables - probably using `$_GET[...]`. You will be able to do the same with `$_GET['customID']` :)